# Shared Memory issue with X-Plane 10

Tags: memory, memory-management, simulation, shared-memory, simulate

I have a program that sends/receives datagrams from X-plane and to other pc which has simulation values. This code works good with x-plane 9 but when changed to x-plane 10 it does not communicate to x-plane now. I open a  socket and send/receive data through shared memory via UDP from x-plane and sim. I have a plugin that works with all these on x-plane 9. This is the way it used to work with x-plane 9 but not in x-plane 10. I have noticed that x-plane establishes a connection but it is unable to receive data that is being sent to it. So does anyone know if there is anything that has to do with the code to be compatible with x-plane 10? Thanks.

Edit: I found on research that my shared memory is not sending the simulation values to x-plane 10 but how come it works for x-plane 9. I see that pointer that points to the address of the shared memory becomes null. Is this anything related to x-plane 10 and x-plane 10 crashes on exit, in crash log it shows some exception c000005. Can anyone help me with this or some kind of idea to get through this hurdle.

Edit2: Shared memory issue: I have a function that creates a handle checks if it null or not and in x function this handle is used and it should have same memory since the handle is not closed anywhere but it shows as 0. So re-created the handle in x function but now it is allocating around 17500 size to that previously it is 5780. I am curious if I don't go to any memory issue because of this. The problem is solved but everything is used to work with x-plane 9 I wonder why not in 10.

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with UDP, but everything to do with how you hook into particular simulator version.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov I figured that UDP has nothing to do with it but the shared memory is the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a function that creates a handle checks if it null or not and in x function this handle is used and it should have same memory since the handle is not closed anywhere but it shows as 0. So re-created the handle in x function but now it is allocating around 17500 size to that previously it is 5780. I am curious if I don't go to any memory issue because of this. The problem is solved but everything is used to work with x-plane 9 I wonder why not in 10.